# Kafka Connect HDFS configuration setting?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to configure Kafka Connect to write the maximum possible of records to HDFS (I need to write around 100B records per day, Each record is around 1.2Kb).

I have Kafka server with 256GB RAM.

I'm trying to configured the following settings:

```
flush.size=305000
tasks.max=215
```

With Kafka topic with 215 partitions.
With this setting I got exception of:

> Java heap space OutOfMemoryException

And with:

```
    flush.size=305000
    tasks.max=10
```

With Kafka topics with 10 partitions, This works fine but write only around 40-50M records in 10min, With this configuration I have very big lag (around 1.5B).

How can I calculate the maximum configuration of Kafka connect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your Kafka Server RAM doesn't matter if you have not set the Java heap size any larger than the defaults.

The same applies to Kafka Connect... That would help with OOM errors

If you have 10 partitions, the you'll want to run 10 tasks *in **distributed** mode*, not standalone. That'll scale out the consumer processes and if you want it to go even faster, run it on 10 separate machines (or a few machines and use Docker containers)

The only way I know you can calculate the max amount of messages you can get within a given flush would be to monitor the used heap space with JMX monitoring on the connect process. 100B records a day in 10 partitions is a lot of records, though, and you'll want to possibly increase that value